# sort Array by another Array like GroupBy NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello I have two array and I want to sort them another array but i want to sort like group by.

```
var a = [1,2,3,2,1,3,3,2,1]
var b = [b,b,b,c,c,c,d,d,d]
```

The result I want like;

```
var a =[3,2,1,3,2,1,3,2,1]
var b =[b,b,b,c,c,c,d,d,d]
```

Comment: What have you already tried? What is the link between the two arrays?

Comment: Im getting array with procedure from Oracledb  but i cannot see from max to min. its coming mix. And I try to fix this from node js

Comment: There doesn't seem any connection between the two arrays at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to sort groups based on the associated letters of each number, you could group each number first by its associated letter from `b` by using a `Map` with `.reduce()`, then sort each group so it's in descending order with `.sort()`. Once each group is sorted, you can flatten your array of groups using `.concat()` like so:

```js
const a = [1,2,3,2,1,3,3,2,1];
const b = ['b','b','b','c','c','c','d','d','d'];

const sortedGroups = [].concat(...Array.from(a.reduce((map, val, i) => 
  map.set(b[i], (map.get(b[i]) || []).concat(val)),
  new Map
).values(), grouped => grouped.sort((a, b) => b-a)));

console.log(sortedGroups);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had an array of pairs like this

```
const arr = [ {a:1, b:'b'} , {a:2, b:'b'}, {a:3, b:'b'},
              {a:2, b:'c'} , {a:1, b:'c'}, {a:3, b:'c'},
              {a:3, b:'d'} , {a:2, b:'d'}, {a:1, b:'d'} ]
```

you would establish a link between the two arrays in your question.

You could sort that array into an order descending on the `a` and ascending on the `b`  like this

```
 arr.sort ( (y,z) => 
      {
         const c = y.b.localeCompare(z.b)
         if (c !== 0) return c
         return z.a - y.a   /* order switched for descending sort */
      } )
```